# Why doesn't SLD validate?

Tags: sld

Why doesn't my SLD validate?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
<UserLayer>
  <Name>raster_layer</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <Name>PM 2.5</Name>
    <Title>PM 2.5 Layers</Title>
    <Abstract>Color Scheme for PM 2.5 Rasters</Abstract>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
      <Rule>
        <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ColorMap type="intervals">
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fafafa" opacity="0.0" quantity="0.0" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fafafa" opacity="0.5" quantity="1.0" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fa0808" opacity="0.5" quantity="100.0" />
         </ColorMap>
        </RasterSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
</UserLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: You need to include the SLD so we can see where the problem is.

Comment: can you share the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you meant to use the *NamedLayer* element, rather than *UserLayer*.

e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
<NamedLayer>
  <Name>raster_layer</Name>
  <UserStyle>
    <Name>PM 2.5</Name>
    <Title>PM 2.5 Layers</Title>
    <Abstract>Color Scheme for PM 2.5 Rasters</Abstract>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
          <FeatureTypeName>Feature</FeatureTypeName>
      <Rule>
        <RasterSymbolizer>
            <ColorMap type="intervals">
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fafafa" opacity="0.0" quantity="0.0" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fafafa" opacity="0.5" quantity="1.0" />
              <ColorMapEntry color="#fa0808" opacity="0.5" quantity="100.0" />
         </ColorMap>
        </RasterSymbolizer>
      </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
  </UserStyle>
</NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```